# UI5: SmartTable Personalisation/Variant Management Error

Tags: sapui5

[image: le]

Hello Experts, I'm unsure why this error (pictured) is appearing. As far as I know, SmartTable should be able to take care of everything to do with variant management, right? In my controller, I dont have any code pertaining to variant management.

Here is the below code for my smartTable:

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable" entitySet="Z9NRS_REQUESTSet" tableType="ResponsiveTable"
    useExportToExcel="true" beforeExport="onBeforeExport" demandPopin="true" useVariantManagement="true" useTablePersonalisation="true" 
    header="Manage Requests" showRowCount="true" persistencyKey="SmartTableAnalytical_Explored" enableAutoBinding="true"
    class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" initiallyVisibleFields="ZNRS_REQUEST,ZREQUESTOR_NAME,ZPRODUCT_FAMILY,ZOEM,ZTIER,ZCUSTOMER_PN,ZMATERIAL_NO,ZSTATUS_DESC,ZCONNECTOR_CONFIG" >
    <smartTable:customToolbar>
        <OverflowToolbar>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <!--<Button icon="sap-icon://settings" type="Accept" />-->
        </OverflowToolbar>
    </smartTable:customToolbar>
    <Table mode="SingleSelectMaster" selectionChange="onPress" inset="false" >
        <columns>
            <Column>
                <Text text="Status"/>
                <customData>
                    <!--p13nData is a keyword that links smartTable to this and let it identify this custom column-->
                    <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey":"ZSTATUS_DESC",
                    "leadingProperty":"ZSTATUS_DESC", "sortProperty":"ZSTATUS_DESC",
                    "filterProperty":"ZSTATUS_DESC", "columnIndex":7}' />
                </customData>
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem >
                <!--<ObjectStatus text="{ZSTATUS_DESC}" />-->
                <ObjectStatus text="{ZSTATUS_DESC}" state="{path:'ZOVERALL_STATUS', formatter:'.formatter.DrawingStatus'}" />
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>                        
    <!-- layout data used to make the table growing but the filter bar fixed -->
    <smartTable:layoutData>
        <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0%"/>
    </smartTable:layoutData>
```

</smartTable:SmartTable>

Comment: Is the persistency key correct and LREP is available there? What's in your console?

Comment: Is there a certain value my persistencyKey should be? I don't know what LREP is. In my console there is an error saying: Connector (LrepConnector) failed call 'loadFeatures': Error. Application startup continues without data from this storage.

Comment: Lrep is the system that stores those smart preferences. It’s the name of the icf node (I think) and the service giving an error. The key is a unique identifier, but it can be anything. I would change it to something else than what you have now

Comment: Is the persistencyKey value set by someone in the backend or can any random value work? I tried a random value 'key1' as the value to persistencyKey but error mentioned in last comment still shows. When I try to save a variant, console gives me: "_save failed".  I really don't see what could go wrong in my XML code...that could be the only place of error, right?

Answer (score 0):

When I deployed and tested variant management it worked. But in FLPSandbox it wasn't working, so I guess it had to do with the app's access to some backend system(?)